# How to create a CLI alias for a web search with W3M?

Tags: command-line, bash, alias, w3m

I would like to create an alias with the function to perform a DuckDuckGo search with W3M via the Command Line Interface (CLI).

I have already created the alias and the DuckDuckGo search engine is called. However, I would also like to enter a search keyword after the alias in the CLI and I do not know how to do that.
Example:

```bsh
alias duckit="w3m https://lite.duckduckgo.com/lite/"
```

When I enter the command `duckit` in the CLI, this alias calls the DuckDuckGo search engine and opens the web page.
But I want the alias to also enter the search keyword in DuckDuckGo and show me the results.

So I tried adding `?q=` at the end of the alias above:

```bsh
alias duckit="w3m https://lite.duckduckgo.com/lite/?q="
```

However, running it as follows does not work:

```
duckit test
```

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use an alias if you need to pass parameters to it, you need to use a function instead. Add this to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
duckit(){
    w3m https://lite.duckduckgo.com/lite/?q="$@"
}
```

Now open a new terminal and try `duckit test`.

Comment: Thank you! - Search terms with blank space must be entered in quotes. Example: **duckit "install w3m ubuntu"**

Comment: @Teso yes. Alternatively, you could use this instead: `duckit(){  w3m https://lite.duckduckgo.com/lite/?q="$*"; }`. But in any case, it is almost always better to pass your arguments quoted.

Comment: Ohh yaaa! I like this better…

Answer (score 0):

**Installation guide**

1. Install the [W3M Web-Browser](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/):

   ```
   sudo apt-get install w3m
   ```
2. Or with image support (shows images on web pages):

   ```
   sudo apt-get install w3m w3m-img
   ```
3. Copy the following command into the CLI and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   ```bsh
   echo 'duckit(){ w3m https://lite.duckduckgo.com/lite/?q="$*"; }' >> ~/.bashrc
   ```

4.Open a **new** CLI and run a search

```
duckitl test my w3m on ddg
```

[image: W3M]

---

**DuckIt - Update Version 0.4**

DuckDuckGo offers a pure HTML version of its search engine.
Since the W3M does not support JavaScript anyway, it is better to use the DDG-HTML page.
This has one advantage, the HTML page contains no scripts and therefore less code. Less code means smaller HTML-file and therefore less data transfer, which makes the page load faster.

```bsh
echo 'duckit(){ w3m https://lite.duckduckgo.com/html/?q="$*"; }' >> ~/.bashrc
```

If you already have DuckIt-W3m installed, just change the string in the `~/.bashrc` file with your favorite text editor (e.g. `nano ~/.bashrc`) from `lite` to `html`.

https://lite.duckduckgo.com/html/

---

**DuckIt - Update Version 0.5**

Some people like the [Lynx web browser](http://lynx.browser.org/) better, so I have two new aliases for you.

The alias has changed.
The DDG-Lynx alias is: `duckitl`

```
sudo apt-get install lynx
```

```bsh
echo 'duckitx(){ lynx https://lite.duckduckgo.com/html/?q="$*"; }' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Open a **new** CLI and run a search:

```
duckitx test my lynx on ddg
```

**Probably the fastest search on Planet.**